ASP.NET utilising click event of imagebutton within datagrid template column
I am struggling to get a datagrid working nicely for me. I realise there may be other controls that can do what I'm planning but i'm a way down the line with the datagrid so would like to see if this is possible. Essentially I have the following datagrid which is being bound to a SQL connection:
<asp:datagrid ID="dginventory" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" Width="99.4%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanged="ChangePage" OnSortCommand="SortGrid" OnEditCommand="dginventory_oneditcommand" OnDeleteCommand="dginventory_ondeletecommand" >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="datagridheader"/>
            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="datagridalternating"/>
            <ItemStyle cssClass="datagriditem"/>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchaseYear" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="YOP" ItemStyle-Width="4%" SortExpression="PurchaseYear ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchaseDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Purchased" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="PurchaseDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle-Width="5%"  SortExpression="Number ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Theme" HeaderText="Theme" ItemStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Theme ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="30%" SortExpression="Name ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RRP" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="RRP" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchasePrice" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Cost" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Discount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Dis." ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:P1}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ReleaseDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Rel. Date" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="ReleaseDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RetireDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Ret. Date" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="RetireDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Retailer" HeaderText="Retailer" ItemStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Retailer ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="StorageLocation" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Box" ItemStyle-Width="3%" SortExpression="StorageLocation ASC" />
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton src="Images/edit-alt-regular-24.png" ID="btneditset" alt="Edit" class="imagebutton" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton src="Images/trash-regular-24.png" ID="btndeleteset" class="imagebutton" CommandName="Delete" runat="server"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
                <PagerStyle NextPageText="Next --&gt;" Font-Bold="True" PrevPageText="&amp;lt-- Prev" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Red" Mode="NumericPages" />
        </asp:datagrid>

As you can see I have two template columns, each containing an image. One for delete and one for Edit. I cannot seem to catch the click events of these image buttons no matter what I try. If I replace one of them with a ButtonColumn then that works fine however that means that I can't use an image.
In the code behind I've setup these:
Sub dginventory_oneditcommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)

    lblfilters.Text = "edit"

End Sub


Sub dginventory_ondeletecommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)

    lblfilters.Text = "delete"

End Sub

Neither one of them seems to actually catch anything. I've also tried using onitemcommand which again doesn't seem to fire. I did try adding an onclick to the two imagebuttons too but again no joy.
Hopefully I've described this well enough. I am using vb.net for the code behind in case that wasn't clear.
Here's hoping....

Ok, the easiest way to do this when dropping in a button, ImageButton, or even a combo box for a row?
Ignore the row command approach, and use a regular click event for the given control.
The only "trick" here is that because the control is nested (in a Repeater, ListView, GridView, DataGrid etc.), then you don't have a property sheet for the given control, and thus can't use the property sheet (or a double click) on the control to create the click event.
However, you are 100% free to add, use and enjoy a click event by typing in markup directly. (and intel-sense will still help you).
I should also point out that a DataGrid is the perhaps the oldest control, and in fact you often not see DataGrid in the tool box.
So, I suggest in most cases to use a GridView. (they are very similar).
And if you "grid" of data has more then a few custom controls, then I suggest using a ListView, as it is far more markup friendly. No worry, and using DataGrid is still ok despite being an older control.
So, so say we have a simple DataGrid like this:
(and note the 2 image buttons).
So, then this:
  <asp:DataGrid ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     DataKeyField="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="45%" >

      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="First" DataField="FirstName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Last" DataField="LastName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="City" DataField="City" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="HotelName" DataField="HotelName" runat="server" />
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" runat="server" />

        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png" Width="48"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>

        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png" width="48"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"

                    />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>

      </Columns>
  </asp:DataGrid>

And code to load the grid looks like this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If


End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    GHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub

And the result is this:

Ok, so let's add a delete click event to the image delete button in above.
So, it looks like this from the editor:

So, as above shows, we are allowed and can with ease use standard click events (or other events) for that given control. This means VERY little reason exists to bother with and trying to use the row command. And bonus is we thus have a separate click event for each control and they are not all mumbled up into one event with a bunch of case statements.
In the code behind, we can then pick up the row information like this:
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim cmdDel As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As DataGridItem = cmdDel.NamingContainer

    Dim PK As Integer = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.ItemIndex)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK
    ' MyRstPE(cmdSQL)

    Debug.Print($"Row index click = {gRow.ItemIndex}")
    Debug.Print($"Database PK for row = {PK}")

End Sub

In above, I show how you get the current row (DataGridItem).
In above, I show how you get the database PK value.
In above, I show how you get the row index.
Note the use of "naming" container. This is supported for ALL data bound controls, and returns the current row item.
So, when I click on a given row button, then I have this in the output/debug window:

So, you are free to use regular click events for controls placed in a GridView, ListView, DataGrid etc.
And the above advice also extends to say dropping in a combo box, or other controls. Their events can also be used, but you have to "type in" the event setting directly into the markup since the control is nested, and thus no property sheet is available.
And for completeness, it fast becomes tiring to type code over and over to pull a data table with supplied SQL, so I have some helper routines I used in above, and use throughout the application.
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function

Public Sub MyRstPE(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "")

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Edit: Introducing a confirm dialog for the delete button
Of course, a delete button is rather dangerous without a confirm prompt.
For a standard button, or say an image button, then such buttons have support for both a client side click event, and a server-side event we are using above.
And if the client side (JavaScript) client event for that given button returns false, then the server-side event does not run. And if the client-side JavaScript code returns true, then the server-side event runs.
However, one extra issue arises when attempting to return true or false from JavaScript.
Most, if not all "cool" or "nice" dialog prompt libraries and utilities in JavaScript (jQuery.UI, sweet Alert etc.) run asynchronous. In other words, most JavaScript code is now non blocking. This means such code does not wait.
So, the simplest approach is to use the JavaScript confirm dialog. This is one of the VERY few features in JavaScript that does halt code.
So, we could for example add this client side click event to the ImageButton:
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png" width="48"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this record');"
                    />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>

In fact, looking at above, we did not even have to write a separate JavaScript routine, but used the JavaScript confirm() dialog. This works with ease since it halts code.
However, it looks rather poor, does not give any formatting options, and a bonus would be if the dialog appeared right beside the button we clicked on.
Hence this:

So, I suggest adopting a really nice dialog utility. They have 100's of uses, and for say some pop dialog to edit a row from a Grid, for deleting confirms, and in fact for just about any kind of confirm type of use case, then adopting a great dialog system is most useful, and something that you can use for years to come.
My current favorite choice is the jQuery.UI dialog. In fact, I turned the whole control into a user control, and now I can just drag + drop that control into a form and use it.
So, the jQuery.UI dialog allows you to place content in a div, and then pop that div. (and it by-passes all known popup blockers, another good reason to use such dialogs).
So, assuming we have jQuery.UI (and jQuery) available in the current page, then our ImageButton (client-side event) becomes this:
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/Content/trashcan1.png" width="48"
                    OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this);"
                    />

And thus, below the data grid, we thus have this JavaScript code:
        <div id="mydeldiv">
            <h4>Delete This hotel</h4>
            <h4><i>(this can't be undone)</i></h4>
        </div>

        <script>
            mydelpromptok = false
            function mydelprompt(btn) {

                if (mydelpromptok) {
                    mydelprompt = false
                    return true
                }

                myDialog = $("#mydeldiv")
                myDialog.dialog({
                    title: "Delete Hotel",
                    modal: true,
                    appendTo: "form",
                    dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                    position: { my: "right top", at: "left bottom", of: btn },
                    dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                    buttons: {
                        Delete: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                            mydelprompt = true
                            btn.click()
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                })
                return false
            }
        </script>

So, when you click on the button, the dialog displays, code continues to run (asynchronous), and it returns false to the button. Now the dialog is displayed. If we hit ok, then we close the dialog, set our flag, and THEN click the button again!!!
This re-triggers the function, but it now returns true, and hence the server-side code stub will run. As noted, the above trick is a way to get around the fact of most nice JavaScript dialog systems are non blocking and they run asynchronous.
The result of the above now is:


Hi Albert, I couldn't get this to work weirdly. I have posted the updated code below. Still doesn't seem to be firing but, unless I am missing something, I have replicated what you'd put in place.

Make sure that ANY code to load the GridView on page load is wrapped inside of a if not ispostback stub. If you re-load and re-bind the GV each time, then you not be able to use the row button click. Remember, page load event fires and runs EVERY time on a post back, and runs before your event code stub each time. Hence, if you re-load and re-bind the GV, then your starting over from scratch each time, and row button events can't be used

thank you for such an amazing response. I did try something similar to that, at one point yesterday, without much success. I have implemented your recommendation but it still doesn't seem to fire the event, or catch the right thing. I've only updated the delete button for now:
<asp:datagrid ID="dginventory" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" Width="99.4%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanged="ChangePage" OnSortCommand="SortGrid">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="datagridheader"/>
            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="datagridalternating"/>
            <ItemStyle cssClass="datagriditem"/>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchaseYear" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="YOP" ItemStyle-Width="4%" SortExpression="PurchaseYear ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchaseDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Purchased" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="PurchaseDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" ItemStyle-Width="5%"  SortExpression="Number ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Theme" HeaderText="Theme" ItemStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Theme ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="30%" SortExpression="Name ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RRP" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="RRP" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PurchasePrice" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Cost" ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Discount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Dis." ItemStyle-Width="4%" DataFormatString="{0:P1}" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ReleaseDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Rel. Date" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="ReleaseDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RetireDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Ret. Date" ItemStyle-Width="7%" DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="RetireDate ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Retailer" HeaderText="Retailer" ItemStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Retailer ASC" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="StorageLocation" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderText="Box" ItemStyle-Width="3%" SortExpression="StorageLocation ASC" />
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Images/edit-alt-regular-24.png" ID="btneditset" class="imagebutton" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Images/trash-regular-24.png" ID="btndeleteset" class="imagebutton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btndeleteset_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
                <PagerStyle NextPageText="Next --&gt;" Font-Bold="True" PrevPageText="&amp;lt-- Prev" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Red" Mode="NumericPages" />
        </asp:datagrid>

Here is the code behind. For now it should just update a label on the form so that I can see something happening. I have also put a breakpoint on this the "lblfilters.Text =" line but that's not breaking either.
    Protected Sub btndeleteset_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    lblfilters.Text = "delete"
End Sub

Although it wasn't in your example I also dropped in the causevalidation = false to make sure I wasn't being hampered but that.
Any ideas? Sorry

That should work. remove the causes validation - that's not likely the issue here. I would use a break-point, or check if you using a update panel or some such. In other words,  you don't show lblfilters in your markup. If using a update panel, then lblfilters might be outside of the update panel, and that thus would not error out, but also not update the label in question.  My posted example works just fine, so there is some missing detail here. My best guess is additional nesting, or that of a update panel being used here.  I would comment out the row command event if you have one.

Ok thank you. I've put a break point on the lblfilters.text line in those onclick events and it never breaks. I'll take another look on Monday with your specific example and see if that works for me and then try and spot any differences.

Found it!!! I used your example to get a working form and then iterated through the changed to make it like mine. The culprit was..... I was rebinding the table contents on page load. Now that I see it it's obvious that was destroying the button and rebuilding it again whenever I clicked on it so it wouldn't ever fire. Thank you again for you excellent example and assistance.

Note my comments and suggestion above - I noted that you near always have to use a is not isPostBack code stub in the page load event, or it fires every time. In fact, you can't really build a working web page without the Is Note IsPostBack stub in that page load event if there is any setup code, or code that loads up controls data

Thank you. At the risk of pushing my luck a little could I ask something else? Is there anyway to get the clicked button's row using clientside code? I have removed the onclick from the delete button and have specified the onclientclick for the delete button to run some javascript code to display a DIV which effectively asks the user for confirmation. Using your example I now know how to get the ID server side but I wonder if it's possible to get the ID client side. I can then pass that to the "Confirm Delete" button to go and commit the deletion in SQL server side. Hope that makes sense.

common requirement to have a "confirm". the "easy" way is to add both a client side click event, and a server side event (as it has now) to the one button. You then have JavaScript code return true if user hits ok, and if user hits cancel (to not delete), then we return false, and the server side button code does not run. -- - so watch for this later today). I going to recommend to use a jQuery.UI dialog, since they work great. So, you no doubt have jquery (its installed by default in most cases), but you have to add jQuery.UI to your project.

See the edit to my post. I show how to pop a jQuery.UI dialog, and confirm the delete. I also should point out that I STRONG suggest you move away from DataGrid, and use Gridview (it is newer, almost the same, but works better). And then if your grid is to have more complex controls and layout, then move up again to the ListView.  (ListView is my favorite for many reasons - but this post is already too long!!!

Amazing Albert! Thank you so much. My first job for the day is to investigate using either Gridview or ListView.
